# CSS3 Background-image hover transition

Tags: css, animation, hover, background-image, transition

please check the following link

http://intelmarketing.mk/demos/security/services/

you will see 3 icons i a row and there is css3 transition on almost all hovers but i can't add the animation to the icons i tried with couple of examples like

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ - example 1

but nothing seams to work also my images are transparent so example 1 is not working as i want, so what i want is when i do mouse over on the box the button and the icon same time to hover smoothly, the button works but the icons don't how can i solve this problem?

css for the first icon:

```
.fastvagticon
{
    width:299px;
    height:166px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url('images/FASTVAGT.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

.servbox:hover .fastvagticon
{
    width:299px;
    height:166px;
    background-image:url('images/FASTVAGTh.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

css for the button

```
.servbtn1
{
    background-color:transparent;
    background-position: right center;
    background-image: url("images/eempy.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 34px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 151px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease;
      border:1px solid #fff;
}

.servbox:hover .servbtn1
{
    width:184px;
    height:34px;
    background-color:#3E1C1E;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 151px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't adding any transition to the icon:

```
.fastvagticon
{
    width:299px;
    height:166px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url('images/FASTVAGT.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Also, I don't know if you are aware but this wont work in Firefox. Firefox doesn't allow any animation of background images.

Comment: i have already tried that doesn't work, let me see on chrome if it work

Comment: yes only on ff doesn;t work just checked the chrome works, didn't know that ff is not allowing this..